# Get curent windows profile in vb 2013

Tags: vb.net, windows, user-accounts

I'm writing a little vb application.
I need to know the Windows user name account that is logged in.
I found this:

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is 
      Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
        ' The application is using Windows authentication.
        ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME.
        Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim username As String = parts(1)
        Return username
    Else
        ' The application is using custom authentication.
        Return My.User.Name
    End If
End Function
```

Is working good but he give me the user that execute the process,so if i start the application with the administration credential this function will give me the administration user.
I need the Windows user not the user that execute the process, how can i do?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the user name of the user who logged in to windows. " Not the one who starts the program"

You need to Import System.Management for this.

```
Imports System.Management

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Coll As ManagementObjectCollection
    Dim LogonName As String
    Dim GetName As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
    Coll = GetName.[Get]()
    LogonName = DirectCast(Coll.Cast(Of ManagementBaseObject)().First()("UserName"), String)
    Dim CleanName() As String = Split(LogonName, "\")
    Label1.Text = CleanName(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: I cant try this becouse it's return me an error on ManagementObjectCollection,ManagementObjectSearcher and ManagementBaseObject. It seem the import but i write it in the first line of code like you.

Comment: @user3893550 You need to write it at the top of your code page.

Comment: Is in the first,look under this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Environment.UserName
```

Returns the user that is running the program

```
Environment.UserDomainName
```

Returns the name of the computer

I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: My.User.UserDomainName doesn't exist. So how can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i add to my references System.Management and now work great. Thanks !